# Java invoice Totals and Averages

Tags: java

I am a newbie, so, nice to meet you! I am in a Java 1 course in college and we have this invoice application. I have written the code, and I can get it to do everything EXCEPT give me the the average invoice amount, and the average discount amount. This is supposed to show if the user enters "n".

I can get it to do all of that including get the total number of invoices, however I get 0.0 as my output for Average Discount and Average Invoice Amount. I have attached the code, I hope you can lead me in the right direction. I'm gonna go work on it some more. I hope to learn something from you today! :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InvoiceApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // welcome the user to the program
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Invoice Total Calculator");
        System.out.println();  // print a blank line

        //initialize variables
        int numberOfInvoices = 0;
        double totalDiscount = 0;
        double totalInvoice = 0;

        // create a Scanner object named sc
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // perform invoice calculations only if "n" or "N" is entered
        String choice = "y";
                while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            // get the invoice subtotal from the user
            System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
            double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();

            // calculate the discount amount and total
            double discountPercent;
            if (subtotal >= 500) {
                discountPercent = .25;
            } else if (subtotal >= 200) {
                discountPercent = .2;
            } else if (subtotal >= 100) {
                discountPercent = .1;
            } else {
                discountPercent = 0.0;
            }
            double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
            double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

            // display the discount amount and total
            String message = "Discount percent: " + discountPercent + "\n"
                           + "Discount amount:  " + discountAmount + "\n"
                           + "Invoice total:    " + total + "\n";            
            System.out.println(message);

            // see if the user wants to continue
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();

            numberOfInvoices ++;

        //displays the invoice numbers, average invoice amount, and average
        //discount
    {
        double averageInvoiceAmount = totalInvoice/numberOfInvoices;
        double averageDiscount = totalDiscount/numberOfInvoices;
        String message2 = "\n"
                        + "Number of Invoices: " + numberOfInvoices + "\n"
                        + "Average Invoice Amount: " + averageInvoiceAmount + "\n"
                        + "Average Discount: " + averageDiscount + "\n";
        System.out.println(message2);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `totalInvoice` and `totalDiscount` are 0...

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned any value to "totalInvoice" and "totalDiscount".
these variables are set to default value i.e. 0.0, so the output you get is 0.0 for "Average Discount" and "Average Invoice Amount".

Update the values for both in your code then you will get proper output.

Comment: I am a little confused by your answer. I was told to keep the value 0 because it will differ based on user input. Do you have any further hints on where I should look or what I need to do? I have literally been working on it NON-STOP for hours. Thank you in advance!